# Oracle date difference to get number of years

Tags: oracle, select

Is there a way to calculate the number of years between dates. Not sure how to do this while accounting for leap and what not. Is it possible to do an IF statement maybe in the SELECT?

Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd use `months_between`, possibly combined with `floor`:

```
select floor(months_between(date '2012-10-10', date '2011-10-10') /12) from dual;

select floor(months_between(date '2012-10-9' , date '2011-10-10') /12) from dual;
```

`floor` makes sure you get down-rounded years. If you want the fractional parts, you obviously want to not use `floor`.

Comment: Nice, i did find another way using Union as well, but thanks.

Comment: I use `select trunc(months_between(date_end,date_start)/12) "Age"    from dual;` to get age.

Answer (score 23):

If you just want the difference in years, there's:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date1) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date2) FROM mytable
```

Or do you want fractional years as well?

```
SELECT (date1 - date2) / 365.242199 FROM mytable
```

365.242199 is 1 year in days, according to Google.

Comment: The difference `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date1) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date2)` is totally wrong way to get number of years
`Ex: date_start = 21-08-2000 , date_end = 01-01-2008`. According to your logic we have **8 years**, but in reality we have **7 complete years**.

Comment: I would argue it hangs on what "difference in years" means, which is not exactly clear. Really, 2008-01-01 - 2000-08-21 is about 7.4 years.

Comment: Additional logic is needed to make this answer accurate.  If the day and month of the subtrahend(to subtracted) is later than the minuend, then a year must be subtracted from the result.

Comment: Yes, John!
It's need test if day and month of a date is equal or greater than day and month of other date and thus, do diference years or diference years - 1

Answer (score 2):

I had to implement a year diff function which works similarly to [sybase](/questions/tagged/sybase) [datediff](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1570/html/blocks/X47295.htm). In that case the real year difference is counted, not the rounded day difference. So if there are two dates separated by one day, the year difference can be 1 (see `select datediff(year, '20141231', '20150101')`).

If the year diff has to be counted this way then use:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_to) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_from)
```

Just for the log the (almost) complete datediff function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datediff (datepart IN VARCHAR2, date_from IN DATE, date_to IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  diff NUMBER;
BEGIN
  diff :=  CASE datepart
    WHEN 'day'   THEN TRUNC(date_to,'DD') - TRUNC(date_from, 'DD')
    WHEN 'week'  THEN (TRUNC(date_to,'DAY') - TRUNC(date_from, 'DAY')) / 7
    WHEN 'month' THEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(date_to, 'MONTH'), TRUNC(date_from, 'MONTH'))
    WHEN 'year'  THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_to) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_from)
  END;
  RETURN diff;
END;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to find difference in year, if leap year the a year is of 366 days.

I dont work in oracle much, please make this better. 
Here is how I did:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN    ( (fromisleapyear = 'Y') AND (frommonth < 3))
               OR ( (toisleapyear = 'Y') AND (tomonth > 2)) THEN
             datedif / 366
          ELSE
             datedif / 365
       END
          yeardifference
  FROM (SELECT datedif,
               frommonth,
               tomonth,
               CASE
                  WHEN (       (MOD (fromyear, 4) = 0)
                           AND (MOD (fromyear, 100) <> 0)
                        OR (MOD (fromyear, 400) = 0)) THEN
                     'Y'
               END
                  fromisleapyear,
               CASE
                  WHEN (   (MOD (toyear, 4) = 0) AND (MOD (toyear, 100) <> 0)
                        OR (MOD (toyear, 400) = 0)) THEN
                     'Y'
               END
                  toisleapyear
          FROM (SELECT (:todate - :fromdate) AS datedif,
                       TO_CHAR (:fromdate, 'YYYY') AS fromyear,
                       TO_CHAR (:fromdate, 'MM') AS frommonth,
                       TO_CHAR (:todate, 'YYYY') AS toyear,
                       TO_CHAR (:todate, 'MM') AS tomonth
                  FROM DUAL))
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle SQL Developer I was able to calculate the difference in years using the below line of SQL. This was to get Years that were within 0 to 10 years difference. You can do a case like shown in some of the other responses to handle your ifs as well. Happy Coding!

`TRUNC((MONTHS_BETWEEN(<DATE_ONE>, <DATE_TWO>) * 31) / 365) > 0 and TRUNC((MONTHS_BETWEEN(<DATE_ONE>, <DATE_TWO>) * 31) / 365) < 10`