# Difference between two dates in years, same month and same day

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
+------------+------------+------+
| start_date |  end_date  | year |
+------------+------------+------+
| 01/01/2001 | 01/01/2002 | 1    |
| 01/01/2001 | 04/01/2002 | 1    |
| 01/01/2001 | 31/12/2001 | 1    |
| 01/01/2001 | 03/01/2011 | 10   |
| 01/01/2001 | 02/01/2101 | 100  |
+------------+------------+------+
```

Having two dates in oracle with the following values:

```
+------------+------------+
| start_date |  end_date  |
+------------+------------+
| 01/01/2001 | 01/01/2002 |
+------------+------------+
```

I'm using the mod to calculate if difference is one year.
MOD(end_date-start_date, 365) = 0

This works for small differences in dates, after 4 years I can't use zero and for

```
start_date  end_date
01/01/2001  01/01/2101

end_date-start_date = 36524
end_date-start_date !=  365 * 100 (36500)

MOD(36500, 365) = 0
but 
MOD(36524, 365) = 24
```

The aim is to understand if the years are inside the interval around 2 year, around 3 year, 
around 4 ....

```
+------------+------------+
| start_date |  end_date  | year between 
+------------+------------+
| 01/06/2013 | 01/06/2015 | 2
+------------+------------+
+------------+------------+
| 01/06/2013 | 08/08/2015 | NA
+------------+------------+
+------------+------------+
| 31/05/2013 | 02/06/2015 | 2
+------------+------------+    
+------------+------------+
| 25/05/2013 | 02/06/2015 | NA
+------------+------------+
```

Any ideas ? I will try to use :

MOD(end_date-start_date, 365.242199)

After testing the MODULE option I decided to go with the following solution idea provided by dnoeth:

```
case when end_date between 
  add_months(start_date, round(months_between(end_date, start_date)/12)*12) - 5 
and   
  add_months(start_date, round(months_between(end_date, start_date)/12)*12) + 5    
then 
  round(months_between(end_date, start_date) / 12)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943055/oracle-date-difference-to-get-number-of-years)

Comment: In this case I want to have a threshold, of 5 days. 2001/01/01 and 2002/01/08 is not a year difference in my case.

Comment: you want difference in days, months or years

Comment: Years, but I need to have the difference in days to understand if it goes from 360 to 370 days
when a full year is 365 days.

Comment: What do you mean by "threshold"? Approximately 1 year, 360 to 370 days? What result do you expect for 380 days? And why it's only 10 years between 01/01/2001 and 03/01/2012?

Comment: Threshold I want the difference to be one year plus 5 or one year less 5. 380 days > 370 so isn't ok for this case.
The 10 years is because it's one year and 2 days, 367 days < 370.

Comment: I don't get it. 01/01/2001 and 01/01/2002 is one year, but 01/01/2001 and 03/01/2012 are 10 years. Again, what result do you expect for 380 days? Or 500 days? Still one year?

Comment: typo 03/01/2011 instead of 03/01/2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an approximate year (5 days less is still considered to be one year) you might simply add five days to your end date and use months_between:

```
TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(end_date+5, start_date)/12)
```

Edit:
After adding more info I think this might work: If it's plus/minus five days based on the strat_date

```
case when add_months(start_date, trunc(months_between(end_date+5, start_date) / 12)*12) 
            between end_date - 5 and end_date + 5
     then trunc(months_between(end_date+5, start_date) / 12) 
end
```

Comment: Add some extra examples to clarify my point, with months between I can't do it because I need to know the value in days.

Comment: Edited my answer, now it's returning NULL if it's not +/- 5 days

Answer (score 1):

Why not use simple `MONTHS_BETWEEN` function?
For example:

```
SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(end_date, start_date)/12) FROM TTABLE
```

---

I.e.:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT TO_DATE('01.01.2001','DD.MM.YYYY') START_DATE,
                      TO_DATE('01.01.2003','DD.MM.YYYY') END_DATE 
               FROM DUAL)
SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(END_DATE, START_DATE)/12) YEARS_BETWEEN FROM dates
```