# Oracle SQL Date doesn't show time? How to show time between two dates?

Tags: oracle, date, time

I want to calculate time between two dates, to show how much time there's left in a Sale. However when I display dates, it only shows the date and not the time (though I inserted date with dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss).

```
SELECT date
FROM Sale
```

This is the Sale entity. (left unrelevant attributes out)

```
CREATE TABLE Sale
(
    dateStart           DATE NOT NULL,
    dateEnd             DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Basically, I just want to show the hours, minutes, seconds left till the sale is over. So dateEnd minus the dateStart...
How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why was SQL tag removed :o

Comment: Have you tried searching? this question seems to be a duplicate of ( among others) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql9)

Answer (score 2):

Dates do not have a format - they are [represented internally by 7 or 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264).

It is the SQL client that formats the date and by default SQL plus will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter (this is a client variable not one that is set globally).

If you want a consistently formatted date then you will need to convert it to a string

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( datestart, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` )
FROM   sale;
```

Comment: Cool I didn't know that, however how am I gonna calculate time difference between two datetimes? TODATE(TO_CHAR)?

Comment: @SJacobs see dcieslak's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36494839/1509264) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1096853/1509264) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943055/oracle-date-difference-to-get-number-of-years).

Answer (score 0):

```
   with dates as
   ( select  to_date('20160401 11:21','yyyymmdd hh24:mi') as date1, 
             to_date('20160327 10:13','yyyymmdd hh24:mi') as date2 
     from dual )
   SELECT floor((date1-date2)*24)
          || ' Hours ' ||
           mod(floor((date1-date2)*24*60),60)
           || ' Minutes ' ||
           mod(floor((date1-date2)*24*60*60),60)
          || ' Secs ' time_difference
     FROM dates;
```

Will produce:

```
    time_difference
   -------------
    121 Hours 7 Minutes 59 Secs
```