# DATE DIFF IN YEARS

Tags: oracle, datediff

How to find date diff in years in **'YYYY-MM-DD'** format .

I am using  below two querues:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(SYSDATE - TO_DATE('1994-08-13')) / 365.25) AS AGE FROM DUAL;
```

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
SELECT (TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_NUMBER('1994-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) FROM DUAL;
```

> O/P-: -727738

Desired o/p:  26

Comment: Try `SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')) FROM DUAL;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle date difference to get number of years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943055/oracle-date-difference-to-get-number-of-years)

Comment: @JohnMitchell- Thank You but I want difference between two years in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: Try `SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1994-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY')) AS ANSWER FROM DUAL; `  Output = 27

Comment: Yes @JohnMitchell but it should be 26 because after august month it should be 27 not now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use "months_between" function because it takes leap years into account (months_between wants 2 dates as parameters):

```
select months_between(sysdate, to_date('1994-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))/12 from dual;

26,4729751904122
```

of course, if you need to truncate:

```
select trunc(months_between(sysdate, to_date('1994-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))/12) from dual;

26
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but can you please explain to me how your answer is different to the accepted answer in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943055/oracle-date-difference-to-get-number-of-years)?

Comment: @Abra, I'm sorry, but I didn't notice your comment; you can imagine, when someone sees many answers that do not satisfy him, he is tempted to give his opinion and does not look in detail at all the comments, however written in such a small way; next time I have to pay more attention to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract one date from the other:

```
sysdate - date '1994-08-13'
```

Or

```
sysdate - to_date('1994-08-13', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

returns the number of days between the two dates.

So rewrite your first query to:

```
select (sysdate - date '1994-08-13')  / 365.25 as age
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

So, **extract** years from these dates and **subtract** them:

```
SQL> select extract (year from sysdate) - extract(year from date '1994-08-13') diff
  2  from dual;

      DIFF
----------
        27

SQL>
```

Because,

```
SQL> select 2021 - 1994 diff from dual;

      DIFF
----------
        27

SQL>
```